# What is the way to add an index column in Dask when reading from a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, dask

I'm trying to process a fairly large dataset that doesn't fit into memory using Pandas when loading it at once so I'm using Dask. However, I'm having difficulty in adding a unique ID column to the dataset once read when using the read_csv method. I keep getting an error (see Code). I'm trying to create an index column so I can set that new column as the index for the data, but the error appears to be telling me to set the index first before creating the column.

## CODE

```
df = dd.read_csv(r'path\to\file\file.csv')  # File does not have a unique ID column, so I have to create one.
df['index_col'] = dd.from_array(np.arange(len(pc_df)))  # Trying to add an index column and fill it
# ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

#### Update

Using `range(1, len(df) + 1` changed the error to: TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, it's hard to know number of lines in each chunk of a CSV file without reading through it, so it's hard to produce an index like `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` if the dataset spans multiple partitions.

One approach would be to create a column of ones:

```
df["idx"] = 1
```

and then call cumsum

```
df["idx"] = df["idx"].cumsum()
```

But note that this does add a bunch of dependencies to the task graph that backs your dataframe, so some operations might not be as parallel as they were before.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know how it goes! Is this generally the way to go when the dataset spans multiple partitions and you're loading the data from a csv?

Comment: Typically people just stop expecting a consistent incrementing index.